# I can't get model returned back from action with ajax method and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a DDL in my index page, I get to the action I want, but nothing happens there although my code is right (I mean the result back is like null). But I don't know how or what to do to get data back from my action although I get a success back (when I try it with some alert notion).

This is my index.cshtml code:

```
$("#SjukhusNamn").change(function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            data: { sjukhus: $(this).val(@Model.SjukhusNamn) },
            success: function (sjukhus) {
                alert("success");
            },
            url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"
        });
});
```

In my action, a simple [HttpPost] and then

```
public ActionResult Index(VardplatsOversiktViewModel model, string sjukhus)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sjukhus))
        {
            model.SjukhusNamn = sjukhus;

            model.ListaVardplatsOversikt = db.tblVardplatsOversikt
                .Where(s => s.Sjukhus == model.SjukhusNamn)
                .ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
}
```

sjukhus is hospital in english.

Comment: you have miss a closing bracket for alert.

Comment: alert("success"; should be alert("success"); I think it is typo.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not that. I had that alert working before. But nothing is changing on the main page where I am choosing something from the DDL. I choose a hospital, the page does not reload with the desired result. But the alert comes up.

Comment: Why are you using the value of your MVC `@Model` variable when posting, instead of just the actual value of the changed `#SjukhusNamn` element?

Comment: if you want a result back you need to return a Partial View (if you want HTML back) or a JSONResult (if you want object data back). Or you could just return a simple string if the answer is that straightforward. But you can't return a whole View - that's an entire HTML page, it makes no sense to get that back from an ajax call.

Comment: I removed that too, `@Model.SjukhusNamn` in the value, but, I don't know if I should write something else there, because it is not working with that removed too. Also, when I push the submit button, then the page loads my desired results, not otherwise.

Comment: Also `data: $(this).val(@Model.SjukhusNamn)` makes no sense either. That syntax _sets_ the value of `this`, it doesn't return anything which could be sent to the server. Did you just mean `data: $(this).val()`, which would return the value of the element, and use it as the data to send?

Comment: Yes, `data: $(this).val()`. Okay, I'll look into returning a JSONResult, since I want to return back a model.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to convert your Object to JSON, then write it to the response.  I like to use [the jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for this, but there are others.  Once you have the Object as a json String, get a PrintWriter and write it to the response with the correct content type:

```
PrintWriter out = null;
logger.info("Replying to client = " + jsonStr);
try {
    out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/json;charset=utf-8");
    out.print(jsonStr);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Error sending response to client: " + e);
}
```